# Why does this character lose their powers in "Titans"?

Tags: dc, titans-2018

In the Netflix series *Titans*, season 2,

> Koriand'r aka Kory Anders aka Starfire

gradually loses their powers throughout the last three or so episodes.

Is there any indication in the comics or elsewhere why this might be the case?